# DNS within termux

Tags: wi-fi, networking, termux

I am using termux to synchronize files across a couple of android devices (probably use rsync later... still experimenting). Presently I use ifconfig to figure out the IP address of the devices, launch sshd and then run scp etc. However the IP addresses change every time the wi-fi connection is reset. So... what are my options within termux to map hostnames to these IP addresses? I am probably looking for something similar to a DNS server.

Comment: If the Wifi is a home Wifi most likely the full privacy mode is active for your or all Wifi networks. This means the MAC address is changing every time you connect to the Wifi and thus the Wifi can not reidentify the device and assigns a new IP address. Most devices have in developer options an entry that configure Wifi privacy mode. Change it to be persistent for each Wifi and the IP should not change every time.

Comment: @Robert thank you. I don't mind the addresses changing. I would really like to assign names to machines like we do with hosts file and DNS.

Comment: That is usually the job of the Wifi router if it also includes DNS services. The only alternative would be to install something like a DynDNS client that updates a DNS record in a DNS server every time the IP address changes.